# vaadin7 @Autowired is null in UI (works on JUnit)

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin7

My goal is to use vaadin 7 and integrate it with Spring. I'm not sure why my trivial `Jmessage` bean is null in the UprintUI class **but** passes the test  `assertNotNull` in my unit test (see code below)?

```
@Component
public class Jmessage
{
    @Value("Green")
    private String baseColor;

    public Jmessage()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n--Jmessage was invoked \n\n");
    }

    public String getBaseColor()
    {
        return baseColor;
    }

    public void setBaseColor(String baseColor)
    {
        this.baseColor = baseColor;
    }
}
```

and in the UI level:

```
@Theme("uprint")
@SpringUI 
public class UprintUI extends UI 
{

   @Autowired
   private Jmessage jmessage;   

   @Override
   protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
   {                      
    if (jmessage!=null) //always null!!! 
        System.out.println(jmessage.getBaseColor());

    ...
}
```

the application-context has

```
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.uprint" />
```

When I activate my tomcat, you can see the message from Jmessage `Jmessage was invoked` in the console but when it comes to the UI (`UprintUI`) it's null.

Now, I tried this [tutorial](https://github.com/Vaadin/spring-tutorial) (from vaadin) and it works. They are using

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
```

when I put those notation on my Jmessage  - nothing, still null.

Any idea why my beans are null?

My JUnit (works)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Jmessage.class)
public class JmessageTest
{
    @Autowired
    private Jmessage jmessage;

    @Test
    public void jmessageNotNull()
    {
        assertNotNull(jmessage);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are both `Jmessage` and `UprintUI` in the package `com.uprint` (or a sub-package of it)?

Comment: What packages are they in? It needs to be somewhere referred to by the `base-package="com.uprint"` attribute of `context:component-scan`

Comment: the bean is located at: com.uprint.beans and the UI in com.uprint.view

Comment: Are you using a SpringVaadinServlet? Are you running it as a spring boot application? In the end the main question is who is initializing your spring context and is supplying UI instances from it...

Comment: I had the same issue, if we can call it. It seems in the main UI, you cannot inject beans, but you can inject applicationContext then get the required bean. Im currently working on an app. and it works like that.

Comment: cool, I'll check (hope you're right)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like we cannot inject  beans in main UI. The bean is not ready yet in init() method.

have a another method and annotate that with @postconstuct which spring will call after UI initialization and check the object. it should not be null at that time.